# How to pass special character in query string in .Net core API?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, special-characters, urlencode

Net core application. I have one GET api as below:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("configId={configId}&quoteId={quoteId}"), EnableQuery()]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Scenario>> GetScenario(string configId, int quoteId)
        {
            var result = await configScenarioService.GetScenarioAsync(configId, quoteId);
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                return result.scenarioResults;
            }
            return new List<Scenario>();
        }
```

I am trying to hit from Postman as below:

```
https://localhost:44362/api/v1/Scenario/configId=JBEL+ASS_60_SG_5.2-145_MY21_T102.5_25y&quoteId=236
```

Unfortunately, this is giving 404 error. Maybe the '+' sign is causing the issue. After looking into some documentation, I tried as below:

```
1. https://localhost:44362/api/v1/Scenario/configId="+ encodeURIComponent(BEL+ASS_60_SG_5.2-145_MY21_T102.5_25y) +"&quoteId=236
```

This didn't work for me and still gave a 404 error.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

since you have + sign you have to encode your url, for + url encoded is
%2B https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

```
..../Scenario?configId=JBEL%2BASS_60_SG_5.2-145_MY21_T102.5_25y&quoteId=236
```

and since you have 404 you have to fix an action route too

```
[Route("~/api/v1/Scenario")]
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Scenario>> GetScenario([FromQuery] string configId, [FromQuery] int quoteId)
```

Comment: Yes this is working from swagger but my JS code files. I have below code const urlEncode = encodeURIComponent(configurationId)    
doGet(`Scenario/GetScenario/configId=${urlEncode}&quoteId=${quote}` when I see in network tab it is getting converted as configId=JBEL%2BASS_60_SG_5.2-145_MY21_T102.5_25y but when i try from swagger it is getting converted as configId=JBEL%252BASS_60_SG_5.2-145_MY21_T102.5_25y So difference in %2 and %252

Comment: @MrPerfect It should be %2B, see my updated answer. You can just try this string.replace("+", "%2B") if you have problems with encoding

Answer (score 2):

Then try this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]/[action]")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    //... ctor and your other stuff

    [HttpGet("{configId}/{quoteId}", Name = "Scenario")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Scenario>)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Scenario>>> GetScenario(string configId, string quoteId)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route, EnableQuery()]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Scenario>> GetScenario([FromQuery(Name = "configId")]string configId, [FromQuery(Name = "quoteId")]int quoteId)
        {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added above code   [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetScenario"), EnableQuery()]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Scenario>> GetScenario([FromQuery(Name = "configId")] string configId, [FromQuery(Name = "quoteId")] int quoteId) but dint work for me

Comment: from javascript also i tried but dint work out for me const urlEncode = encodeURIComponent(configurationId)    
doGet(`Scenario/configId=${urlEncode}&quoteId=${quote}`

Answer (score -1):

what worked is `const urlEncode = encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(configId))` but still i am unable to figure it why i should use `encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent)` in my js